# Django trigger custom function inside template

Tags: python, django

It is possible in Django to call a function from view into template numerous times?

Something like

```
Load A data into template 
Call function in template and filter the query with A.id from template
Load the filtered data in template
Repeat for n times
```

Or should I use Ajax?

Comment: Probably, yes, with template tags. It sounds like you have the wrong idea of Django templates though. I suggest you read the Django documentation on templates completely otherwise you'll run into trouble.

Comment: @joe You can't load data dynamically with template tags any more than in normal templates. What OP is trying to achieve is not possible without AJAX.

Comment: @Ergusto it's possible without Ajax, it's ugly, but possible! :)

Comment: @limelights do you have an example?

Comment: Use a normal form and a select and reload the page each time you filter. Everything is possible to do without Ajax :) Op doesn't necessarily specify that it has to be ajax. Conceptual [dpaste](http://dpaste.com/1321732/)

Comment: @dpaste Right, but that wouldn't be calling it from the template. (The point of the question.) You'd still be performing the action in the view, which would happen in-between the page reloads.

Comment: @Ergusto to be honest I don't think the question is clear enough to know what tHIScOdeIsBeNaNaS is actually asking. Most things can be done with templates. What I was saying is, you shouldn't use templates for this task even if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to use AJAX. Django templates are not dynamic.